# iCalendar file for event spanning multiple days with different times

Tags: icalendar

I have an event to render in iCalendar format that spans 3 days with a different time on each day.  How can I most effectively render this in an iCalendar file?  The [iCalendar spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.2) seems to say that recurrence dates only allow the date component, not the time component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way.  I think the only way might be to have 3 events day1, day2, day 3. You could experiment with using

RELATED-TO
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.5

and

RELTYPE
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.15

to link the events. (maybe with a parent event that is the 3 day one for folks who just want to book out the whole 3 days?)

I haven't tried it yet myself, so I don't know how well supported it is by various calendar applications, or how it would  be shown/interpreted or used.

There are some draft documents about the use:

http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-douglass-link-extension-01.xml#related-to
http://microformats.org/wiki/User:TobyInk/hcalendar-1.1#Related-To_Links

If you do discover anything around this, please post back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

RELATED-TO is not the answer.

You should simply make a recurring event, spanning the 3 days. Then, for each occurrence you create an exception. You do this by simply adding another VEVENT object, giving it the same UID as the initial one, and use the RECURRENCE-ID property.

The RECURRENCE-ID property must contain the full DateTime of the 'original' occurrence. In other words, it should contain the date and time of the occurrence it overrides.

Answer (score 0):

say your events are on Nov 6,7,8 and times are 10 11 and 12 respectively you could have:

```
DTSTART:20121106T100000Z
DURATION:PT15M
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=3;BYHOUR=10,11,12;BYSETPOS=1,5,9
```

however you may want to check your calendar sw supports this combination !